# RxJava (+Room): Why Flowable<List<MyObject>> returns List<List<MyObject>>?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

My Room query(from MyObjectDao) with `Flowable<List<MyObject>>` is returning `List<List<MyObject>>` when running tests. Here is the query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myobjects")
Flowable<List<MyObject>> getAllMyObjects();
```

Here is how I am extracting the first MyObject from the query:

```
MyObject toDelete = myObjectDao.getAllMyObjects().test().values().get(0).get(0);
```

As you can see, I am getting a `List<List<MyObject>>` from the query? Why is that? Why is it getting wrapped inside another List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`values()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#values--) returns all the emissions acquired over the lifetime of your `Flowable`. As each emission from your `Flowable` is a `List`, `values()` will return a list of all y our emissions of lists.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense. Do you have any suggestions on how to test my Flowable if it will only have 1 emission (or if I know the total amount)? Is the way I am doing it OK?

Comment: You can still use it, just assert that `valueCount()` is `1` (or whatever you expect the number of emissions to be) before you do anything else

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated.